# How to decompose a 2d shape into sin and cosin modes?

Tags: geometry, fourier-series, circles, matlab, fast-fourier-transform

Assume that you have a circle with radius $r_0$, then you keep adding cosine modes as below:

$r=r_0+a_1\cos(1\theta)+a_2\cos(2\theta)+a_3\cos(3\theta)+a_4\cos(4\theta)+~...$

if you plot this as below by matlab:

```
r0=1;
a1=0.2;
a2=0.2;
a3=0.2;
a4=0.2;
th=0:0.01:2*pi;
r=r0+a1cos(th)+a2cos(2*th)+a3cos(3*th)+a4cos(4*th);
x=r*cos(th);
y=r*sin(th);
plot(x,y);
```

You will see that you can get different shapes by changing the number of modes (i.e. here n=4) or coefficients (i.e. $a_i$) and even omitting some modes (i.e. $a_k=0$) you will get different shapes.

My question is that how can you decompose for instance an oval or a square in cosine modes, and find their coefficients (somehow in the way of fourier decomposition), is it ever possible?

But I think making any shape would be possible by my method mentioned above, but I am interested to know how I can come from an arbitrary shape to its corresponding cosine modes.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but this is a really interesting question. I'm experimenting and doing research with it right now. I can tell you that some shapes are impossible. (I won't explain why right now). I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Polygon yes it is a good question, but could you give a simple example at least or a hint that help me in my thinking on it.

Comment: @soeil I don't have any examples or hints. It's pretty complicated. I don't even know if it's possible to make squares or ellipses, but I'm working on it.

Comment: @soeil I've been working on this, and I hate to say it, but I'm pretty sure a square is impossible. I'll keep trying different things and keep you updated.

Comment: @soeil https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iscrqhnp7s This is the closest I can get to a square. I'm actually pretty proud of the process I came up with to make it. I can't explain it all right now, but you can try to decipher it if you want. As you can see, it's very far from perfect, but it's pretty cool how it has a fractal-like shape.

Comment: @Polygon Thanks for the update, I looked at the link cited, it looks cool, however I need to try to see how far I can go with the way you have came to that.
Let's not stick to square, how if we say we generate a known shape from a circle with adding the first two cosine modes. Then try to find out how to find the cosine coefficients that we initially used to build up the shape with.

Comment: The title also mentions sin modes, the text does not. Do you want to include these? Essentially you have a periodic function $r(\theta)$. I'd say that writing this as a linear combination $\sum_ka_k\sin(k\theta)+b_k\cos(k\theta)$ is not just “somehow in the way of fourier decomposition” but in fact *is* Fourier decomposition. Did I miss some relevant difference here? If $r(\theta)$ is *not* a function but a relation (i.e. if you have more than two points on the shape for every line through the origin), then you can't get the shape via this method.

Comment: MvG is right. For the square, try $1.122-0.156 \cos (4\theta)+0.049 \cos (8\theta)-0.023 \cos (12\theta)+\cdots$.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comment, but could you say how you came to this relation for a square? Or the method that you computed the mode coefficients?

Comment: For a square the function is $r(\theta)=1/\cos(\theta)$ for $-\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/4$ and extended periodically thereafter. Its Fourier series can be computed using numerical integration, or using a computer algebra software, for example: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+4%2Fpi+cos%284t%29%2Fcos%28t%29+from+-pi%2F4+to+pi%2F4.